# What does $\frac{k_{11}}{k_{21}}$ mean and what is its value?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm reading a scientific article. It says that:
Consider the following matrix:
$$[T]=C\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 &  \rho  \\
 0 &  \eta  & 0 \\
  \rho ^* & 0 &  \zeta  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The eigenvalues of $[T]$ will be:
$$\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2} C \left(\zeta +1+\sqrt{\Delta}\right)$$
$$\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2} C \left(\zeta +1-\sqrt{\Delta}\right)$$
$$\lambda_3=C \eta$$
And the corresponding eigenvectors will be:
$$k_1=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}-\zeta +1}{2 \rho ^*}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$k_2=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}+\zeta -1}{2 \rho ^*}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$k_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Usind the shorthand notation $\Delta = 4 \left| \rho \right| ^2+(\zeta -1)^2$
then
$$\frac{k_{11}}{k_{21}}=-\frac{(\zeta-1-\sqrt{\Delta})^2}{4|\rho|^2}$$
I don't even understand what is $\frac{k_{11}}{k_{21}}$ to start and compute it to see whether it is calculated correctly or not?

Comment: I'm guessing $k_{11}$ refers to the first entry of $k_1$, and $k_{21}$ refers to the first entry of $k_2$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wait, what's $\xi$? It only appears in the last equation.

Comment: Oh , that is zeta. K made a mistake. Please edit it. I'm on mobile now and I can't edit

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger

Comment: I'm on mobile, too. I don't know why that makes it harder for you to edit things. I'm using the app; maybe you're using a browser? In any case, I edited it.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger on mobile keyboard (android) there are limited characters to type latex codes. For example I don't have the character "\"

Comment: Huh. I have an iPhone so that would explain it. (Are you sure there's no way to do it? Maybe try looking it up on Google…)

Answer (score 1):

$k_{11}$ appears to be the first entry in the eigenvector $k_1$, and $k_{21}$ appears to be the first entry in the eigenvector $k_2$. The quotient $k_{11}/k_{21}$ and its expression in the paper should be what you obtain after substituting these two elements and simplifying that quotient algebraically.

Comment: Well I've tried so far to simplify the fraction and get that answer but I couldn't. Could you show me how do you get that last simplified expression for k11/k21 ?

Comment: @sepideh Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{\Delta}-(\zeta - 1)$ and expand $\Delta$.